# How to include javascript script links to pyrocms page?

Tags: templates, codeigniter, template-engine, pyro, dwoo

I'm using pyrocms to develop a system.

I know that, to include style links in header tag ''
in a page is by using $this->template->set_metadata().

But how can I include javascript links like that?

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$this->template->append_metadata(js('foo.js)) will work, or you can dump it into the view as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if this is for a theme and the script is housed within your actual theme/js folder, it becomes:

```
{{ theme:js file="file.js" }}
```

Using just the {js} function would send it to the actual system's embedded js files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a template you can do it like this:

```
{js('file.js', 'modulename')}
```

See the [Pyro documentation](http://pyrocms.com/documentation/designers-guide/functions-variables).

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please explain more clearly what you want. E.g. in which file exactly do you want to include your javascript?

Comment: Thank you captaintokyo! Very helpful!